# Kafka connect - connector per event type

Tags: jdbc, apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I'm using kafka to transfer application events to the sql hisotrical database. The events are structured differently depending on the type eg. `OrderEvent`, `ProductEvent` and both have the relation `Order.productId = Product.id`. I want to store this events in seperate sql tables. I came up with two approaches to transfer this data, but each has a technical problem.

1. `Topic per event type` - this approach is easy to configure, but the order of events is not guaranteed with multiple topics, so there may be problem when product doesn't exist yet when the order is consumed. This may be solved with foreign keys in the database, so the consumer of the order topic will fail until the product be available in database.
2. `One topic and multiple event types` - using the schema regisrty it is possible to store multiple event types in one topic. Events are now properly ordered but I've stucked with jdbc connector configuration. I haven't found any solution how to set the sql table name depending of the event type. Is it possible to configure connector per event type?

Is the first approach with foreign keys correct? Is it possible to configure connector per event type in the second approach? Maybe there is another solution?

Comment: If you have matching ids, you could join the topics before writing to the database. Then you're guaranteed to have data from both events

Comment: @OneCricketeer this brings me to the second mentioned problem, how to put these two events into separate sql tables?

Comment: From Kafka Connect you can't, but if you used something else like Spark, you would just parse the record and build two different dataframes to insert into the tables

Comment: @OneCricketeer I don't want to engage Spark for such simple thing. Right now I will try the first approach - connector per topic. Question is what approach is better: live with the fact that the product may be unavailable for a while or block the orders consumer using the foreign keys until the product be available in database.

Comment: You could also use a regular consumer and a regular database client. But to answer your question, you have eventual consistency. That'll only be a problem for downstream clients that actually need to query the data to re-join the tables. Or you can make a VIEW with an OUTER JOIN that returns all data but with NULL columns for the missing data. The other option is to not use a SQL database and use a document store that can actually nest the full product+order info.

Comment: If you want to use the one topic approach, you might use keys for the messages on the topic and, using a custom serializer, your keys might contain the event type info. If you want to preserve ordering the topic must have anyway a single partition and so you limit the available throughput. It is not clear the sink connector you are using anyway. Is it confluent jdbc sink connector? If so I cannot see any configuration needed to generate custom insert on two different tables. The first approach seems more friendly and easily scalable.